# Finding the specific product series $\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{2a(n-i)}{(n-i)^2(n-i+1)+2b}$

Tags: calculus, products

I am trying to find a solution the product series, but denominator has a form x+y, so it makes complicated calculation as follows. 
Please help to find a product.

$\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{2a(n-i)}{(n-i)^2(n-i+1)+2b}$

I really appreciated your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see what you could do beside using Pochhammer symbols.

Expand the denominator
$$(n-i)^2(n-i+1)+2b=\left(2 b+n^2+n^3\right)- n\left(3 n+2 \right)i+ (3
   n+1)i^2-i^3$$ and let $(r,s,t)$ to be the roots of the cubic in $i$. So
$$P_k=\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{2a(n-i)}{(n-i)^2(n-i+1)+2b}=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}2a(i-n)}  {\prod_{i=1}^{k-1} (i-r) \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} (i-s)\prod_{i=1}^{k-1} (i-t)}$$
$$P_k=\frac{(2a)^{k-1}  (1-n)_{k-1}}{(1-r)_{k-1} (1-s)_{k-1} (1-t)_{k-1}}$$

*Assuming* $b >0$, the cubic equation has only one real root
$$r=n+\frac{1}{3} \left(1-2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}(1+27 b)\right)\right)$$ and two complex conjugate roots which can write $s=c+I\,d$ and $t=c-I\,d$ (first time I have to write a capital $I$ for $I^2=-1$); in fact, by Vieta, we know the sum $(r+s+t)$ and the product $(r\,s\,t)$ so we know $c$ and $d$.
$$\prod_{i=1}^{k-1} (i-s)\prod_{i=1}^{k-1} (i-t)=(1-c-I d)_{k-1} (1-c+I d)_{k-1}$$

Comment: What would be supposed to be the two complex conjugate roots? I really appreciated your help and valuable comments in advanced.

Comment: @JongH. See my edit